# php login script not reading more than two rows of the database records

Tags: php

I have a php login script that is not reading more than two rows of the database user records. it allows the first two users in the database to login and denies the rest. what can i do.

this is the code

```
<?php 

session_start();

$host="localhost";
$myusername="root";
$mypassword="blaze";
$db_name="schoolmaxtas";

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $myusername, $mypassword, $db_name);

if (!$con){
      die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }


  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];


  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if($count==1){
       $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
       $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

      header("location:records.php");

  }
  else{
     echo "incorrect username or password";
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: obtain two records!!, one idea is to make username field unique in the database

Comment: Try running the SELECT statement directly on the database and check the results

Comment: Sharing you table schema might help

Comment: Are you storing raw passwords in your database table?

Answer (score 0):

if username or password in your table is not unique it is better you have this IF

```
if($count>=1){
       $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
       $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

      header("location:records.php");

  }
  else{
     echo "incorrect username or password";
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

If your db schema allows for non-unique usernames, this code could potentially return two rows if both the username and password are duplicated and stop it from working.

```
if($count > 0 )
```

Will serve you better.

Also, never put $_POST values directly into a database query, you should always sanitize first to remove any characters which could affect the query, it's an important habit to get into:

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
```

Answer (score -3):

you have use mysqli so put this code

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($con,$result);
```

Comment: As per [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php), mysql_num_rows expects just one parameter, which is mysqli_result. It doesn't need the connection object,